# Protege - Create inferred data property value

Tags: protege

What I want to do is that, having a specific ontology, to create a new Class and make it so that every instance of the class has a property with a specific value. What I was thinking is, for example, if I have the class `MoviesOf1994` and the data property `productionYear`, I could make `MoviesOf1994` a subclass of `productionYear value 1994`, and from the inferred knowledge every member of `MoviesOf1994` will acquire a data property `productionYear` with a value of 1994. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, but not in the terms you are thinking. Inheritance in OWL doesn't work the way you may be used to in traditional object oriented languages.

Say you have created a class `MoviesOf1994` as the subclass of `productionYear value 1994`. Because of the open world assumption if you create an individual of type `MoviesOf1994` it does not add the dataproperty `productionYear 1994` to it. However if you create an individual and give it the property `productionYear 1994`, it is inferred to be a part of class `MoviesOf1994`

To do what you were asking, you need to be able to explicitly state that anything without the property `productionYear 1994` is not `MoviesOf1994`, which is a very difficult task (impossible I think, but I may be wrong).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did find a workaround to do exactly, but only, what I wanted. The results are unable to be combined with further work. I will post my solution shortly.